# how to stop mouse movement in jquery

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, mouse

i want stop mouse move when left mouse is movedown and mouse X position is on 1920(end of wide screen)

```
$(document).mousedown(function(e) {
   if ( e.pageX <= 1920)
   {
       // move mouse as normal
   }
   else
   {
      // stop mouse movement
   }
})
```

is there any why for stop mouse movement? I don't want pan screen more than of 1920px

Solution:

I found a way for that
It's hide the scroll bar and then overflow events ignored

```
$('body').css('overflow','hidden');
```

Thank you

Comment: Sounds like a XY problem:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem   Now maybe better explain what do you mean by: `stop mouse movement`?

Comment: my mean is when user doing mouse down and drag more than of 1920px; screen will be shift to right and horizontal scrollbar will be appear , i want stop mouse movement when mouse is on 1920px on x vector

Comment: So ask question regarding this issue, not the workaround you think would fix it. Anyway, there is no way in javascript to avoid user moving is mouse. Maybe what you need is just to trigger mouseup event to stop element to be dragged or use some containment option for dragged element or... Impossible to say without seeing any relevant code

Comment: id don't want stop the mouse, i want just user can't go to a pixel is outside of screen like pixel 1950 or etc